# Using excel an excel list to search an excel matrix

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula, formula

I have a matrix in excel, listing a whole slew of attributes/traits (Arbitrary example below). On a second sheet, a user submitted attributes for their dream pet.

??Question?? How can I make a formula that uses the users list, scans the Matrix, and spits out the column heading that most relates to their selected dream attributes.

User selection:
Hair Length: None.
Number of legs: Four.
Color: Gray

`+----------------+----------------------+-------+-------------+
|                | Dog                  | T-Rex | Lizard      |
+----------------+----------------------+-------+-------------+
| Hair Length    | Long, short          | None  | None        |
+----------------+----------------------+-------+-------------+
| Number of legs | Four                 | Two   | Four        |
+----------------+----------------------+-------+-------------+
| Color          | Brown, Gray, Black   | Gray  | Green, Gray |
+----------------+----------------------+-------+-------------+`

**Result: *Lizard***

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use array formula:

```
{=INDEX($A$1:$D$4;1;SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$D$2=G2)*($A$3:$D$3=G3)*NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(G4;$A$4:$D$4)));COLUMN($A$1:$D$4)))}
```

[image]

Array formulas can be entered after typing by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.